# No userfolder in the user folder and in in the public network

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, file-sharing

after I create a new user ( it deosn`t matter wich kind of user) on a Windows 2008 R2 server, there is no folder for the user in the library and no folder in the public network. Should not the server create the folder automatically? I made the user with Active Directory-administrationcenter.
Futhermore there is a problem with the roamingprofil of the user. It said, there is a problem, but which kind of problem I do not know. I guess both problems are connected. I am a newbie and a little bit desperately^^. 
Thank you for your help

Best regards 
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

New folder structure is created after first login on the machine where you logged on or on one specified machine if you using Folder Redirection/Roaming Profile (not sure about the second one).

If you have problem, you have to specify what kind of problem is that.

Answer (score 0):

The home folder can create itself or not..

It depend on the configuration set when you create a user. A home folder set within AD user and computer MMC will try to create itselft automaticly. A home folder not set there, but just mapped by GPP or GPO will not be created by default.

Roaming profile on the other hand will create itselft, and if you have redirected folder they will create themselft IF the necessary path is valid.